# How to through struct's fieldName get value

Tags: go, struct, reflect

```
type mcat struct {
    ID int
}
type cat struct {
    Name string
    M    mcat
}

func getValue(path string, mcat cat){
    //throuth struct path get the value
}

func main(){
    mycat := cat{"cat", mcat{1}}
    id := getvalue("/M/ID", mycat)
}
```

Can I do this by reflecting to get a value based on the field name?

Comment: You have to use package reflect.

Answer (score 0):

You may do what you want with the [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) function. Just range over the parts of the path which may be splitted using [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split).

Here's an example:

```
func getValue(i interface{}, path string) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    for _, field := range strings.Split(path[1:], "/") {
        v = v.FieldByName(field)
    }
    return v.Interface()
}

func main() {
    mycat := cat{"cat", mcat{1}}
    id := getValue(mycat, "/M/ID")
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-Gzk90D2jf7)):

```
1
```

**Some things to note:**

The above solution works for all struct types, not just with `cat`. Checks if the passed value is a struct or the field exists is omitted.

I cut of the leading `/` of the path with a slice expression: `path[1:]` so we don't have to deal with an empty field name inside the loop.

The above `getValue()` returns the result as an `interface{}`. If you need the `ID` as an `int`, you may use type assertion like this:

```
var intID int
intID = id.(int)
```

Also note that it may be nicer / more useful to use a variadic parameter for the path:

```
func getValue(i interface{}, path ...string) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    for _, field := range path {
        v = v.FieldByName(field)
    }
    return v.Interface()
}

func main() {
    mycat := cat{"cat", mcat{1}}
    id := getValue(mycat, "M", "ID")
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OyMDHxrJW4Q).